# Search multiple excel csv files with python and return row

Tags: python, arrays, excel, csv

I have a program that searches 1 excel csv file for a date in column A and returns the row for that search. I now want to expand and search an array of dates and search a variety of excel files for that date.

So, for example. My input array would be:

```
[11202004,11212006,2192008,6102001]
```

Then the program should search all the excel csv files (date1.csv,date2.csv,date3.csv,etc) for those dates and return an array of arrays with the row data.

The output should be:

```
[[11202004,111,222,333],[11212006,444,555,666],[2192008,777,888,999],[6102001,120,234,566]]
```

My code:

```
date_to_find = '2102006'
x = 1
myarr = range(20)
while(x < 20):
    with open('date'+str(x)+'.csv', 'r') as f:
        myarr[x] = next((line for line in csv.reader(f) if line[0] == date_to_find),'')
    x += 1


return myarr
```

Comment: What is the problem? Besides, csv file is just a text file. Normally we do not call it 'Excel csv file'.

Comment: @AnthonyKong nothing. I figured it out. Thanks!